# Replace text between START & END strings excluding the END string in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I was going through examples and questions on the web related to finding and replacing a text between two strings (say START and END) using perl. And I was successful in doing that with the provided solutions. In this case my START and END are also inclusive to replacement text. The syntax I used was `s/START(.*?)END/replace_text/s` to replace multiple lines between START and END but stop replacing when first occurrence of END is hit.

But I would like to know how to replace a text between START and END excluding END like this in perl only.

Before:

```
START
I am learning patten matching.
I am using perl.
END
```

After:

```
Successfully replaced.
END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To perform the check but avoid matching the characters you can use [positive look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
s/START.*?(?=END)/replace_text/s
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to capture the `END` and use it in the replacement text.

```
s/START(.*?)(END)/replace_text$2/s
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using range operator `..` to ignore every line of input until you find the end marker of a block, then output the replace string and end marker:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $rep_str = 'Successfully replaced.';

while (<>) {
    my $switch = m/^START/ .. /^END/;
    print unless $switch;
    print "$rep_str\n$_" if $switch =~ m/E0$/;
}
```

---

It is quite easy to adapt it to work for an array of string:

```
foreach (@strings) {
     my $switch = ...
     ...
}
```

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Another print is needed, because there may be other lines outside those `START` .. `END` block. That `feature` is part of my Perl template, I forget to remove it when I paste that code. Thank you for pointed out the flaws in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To use look-around assertions you need to redefine the input record separator (`$/`) (see [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)), perhaps to slurp the while file into memory.  To avoid this, the [range](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) ("flip-flop") operator is quite useful:

```
while (<>) {
    if (/^START/../^END/) {
        next unless m{^END};
        print "substituted_text\n";
        print;
    }
    else {
        print;
    }
}
```

The above preserves any lines in the output that precede or follow the START/END block.